# Universe Design tool stopped working error in Business objects 4.1 SP5

Tags: business-objects

Recently I installed Business Objects BI 4.1 client tools and Live Office **SP5**. Previously I had Business Objects XI 3.1 (before installing BI 4.1, I completely uninstalled XI 3.1).

Now when I try to launch the Universe Design Tool I am getting an error stating *universe design tool has stopped working*. It would be a great help if anyone suggest solution.

[image: error]

Comment: It would help if you could post a screenshot of the error and perhaps the contents of the UDT logfile (`.glf`).

Comment: hi.. i have added the error link to the above question. (http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp59L.png)